# how to use parameter with calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

person  quantity
A   2
B   3
C   4
D   5
E   8
F   10
G   15
H   20
I   55
J   30
K   21
L   4
M   6
N   10
O   25
P   22

No of people having quantity <25

No of people having quantity >25

please help for the above questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what you need to do is make a parameter of the type string:

[image]

Then you make a field that is working from the values set in the parameter. Use a case statement which has the logic "If the parameter is x, do this; if y do this"

For the "do this" part, you can use an if statement as well:

```
CASE [Quantity Paramter]
WHEN ">= 25 Quantity" THEN IF [Quantity] >= 25 THEN [Person] END
WHEN "< 25 Quantity" THEN IF [Quantity] < 25 THEN Person END

END
```

[image]

This newly created field is your new Person field and so you should drag that onto the Columns or Rows pills

Make sure to exclude the null values by using a filter on your new field. The null values in this context are the values that are not satisfying what you've chosen in the parameter. So if you've selected >=25, then a person with 2 would be a null

The below is demonstrating it working with the sample data:

```
Person  Quantity
A   3
B   57
C   4
D   5
E   10
F   50
G   7
H   3
I   2
```

[image]